# What happens with the app lifecycle when the device shuts down

Tags: win-universal-app

Two scenarios:

1. User turns the device off while app is running.
2. The device shuts itself off because battery is low while app is running.

What happens with the lifecycle? If I understand correctly, when the user closes the app the app is suspended and then terminated. What happens in both scenarios?

I haven't been able to debug it, because the app is not suspended when connected to a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I have **tested** it on my **computer** and **windows phone**. Based on my test results, app **behaves differently** according to **different devices** when the device **shuts down**.  Following is my test results:
**For scenario 1:** User turns the device off while app is running.
On computer (Edition: Windows 10 Enterprise, Version: 1511, OS Build: 10586.218): **App terminated without suspending**.
On Windows Phone (Lumia 929 and Lumia 950, Version: 1511, OS Build: 10586.218): **App suspended**, **then terminated**.
**For scenario 2:** The device shuts itself off because battery is low while app is running.
On Windows Phone (Lumia 929, Version: 1511, OS Build: 10586.218): **App suspended, then terminated**.
I **haven’t** tested it on **all devices**, so you can use the following test solution to **test on your own devices** according to your requirement.
**My test solution:**

1. Store the current time into Local Settings When the app is
   suspending.
2. Turn the device off while app is running (scenario 1), or wait the
   device shuts itself off because battery is low while app is running
   (scenario 2).
3. Turn on the device, run the app again, and load the data from the
   Local Settings to find out the last suspended time. If the last
   suspended time is the time when the device was shut down, then the
   app was suspended first and then terminated. Or else the app just
   terminated without suspending.

**My test code:**
App.xaml.cs

```
private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
    //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
    MainPage.SaveData();
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static void SaveData()
    {
        ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["txt"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    private void btnShowText_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        object settingVal = null;
        if (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.TryGetValue("txt", out settingVal))
        {
            txtToSave.Text = settingVal.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Name="btnShowText"
            Width="250"
            Margin="10"
            Background="Gray"
            Click="btnShowText_Click">
        Get the last suspended time
    </Button>
    <TextBox Name="txtToSave"
             Width="200"
             Margin="10"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Header="Last suspended time:"
             IsReadOnly="True"
             TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you turn off device while the app is running, it is terminated.

You can debug the suspended state of the app using Visual Studio, press F5 to enter normal debug mode. Then use `Lifecycle Events` from the top toolbar to debug suspended, resume events. More about that here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974425.aspx

Comment: I knew how to use the lifecycle events in VS. I can't use that to simulate device shutdown. When the device shuts down, there is no way to do something just before the app terminates?

Comment: There is no way to do anything in case of app terminated when device shutdown / kill process.